# Send command to console application from PHP

Tags: php, windows, console

I have started console application in windows. How can I send commands to it from .php file? This is game server, which accept commans like `kick:player_id`. I want to kick players automatically from my PHP code, I cant do it itself... Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show any PHP code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function like exec or system.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

---

This is not a standard protocol.

I think you need to simulate the keyboard operation.

But PHP is not a good idea. I use Python do this.

```
# demo
import win32api
import win32con
win32api.keybd_event(17,0,0,0) #input ctrl
win32api.keybd_event(86,0,0,0) #input v
win32api.keybd_event(86,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)
win32api.keybd_event(17,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)
```

---

Rocket can use telnet to control unturned.
https://github.com/RocketFoundation/Rocket

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

class Telnet {
 var $sock = NULL;

 function telnet($host,$port) {
  $this->sock = fsockopen($host,$port);
  socket_set_timeout($this->sock,2,0);
 }

 function close() {
  if ($this->sock)  fclose($this->sock);
  $this->sock = NULL;
 }

 function write($buffer) {
  $buffer = str_replace(chr(255),chr(255).chr(255),$buffer);
  fwrite($this->sock,$buffer);
 }

 function getc() {
  return fgetc($this->sock); 
 }

 function read_till($what) {
  $buf = '';
  while (1) {
   $IAC = chr(255);

   $DONT = chr(254);
   $DO = chr(253);

   $WONT = chr(252);
   $WILL = chr(251);

   $theNULL = chr(0);

   $c = $this->getc();

   if ($c === false) return $buf;
   if ($c == $theNULL) {
    continue;
   }

   if ($c == "1") {
    continue;
   }

   if ($c != $IAC) {
    $buf .= $c;

    if ($what == (substr($buf,strlen($buf)-strlen($what)))) {
     return $buf;
    }
    else {
     continue;
    }
   }

   $c = $this->getc();

   if ($c == $IAC) {
   $buf .= $c;
   }
   else if (($c == $DO) || ($c == $DONT)) {
    $opt = $this->getc();
    // echo "we wont ".ord($opt)."\n";
    fwrite($this->sock,$IAC.$WONT.$opt);
   }
   elseif (($c == $WILL) || ($c == $WONT)) {
    $opt = $this->getc();
    // echo "we dont ".ord($opt)."\n";
    fwrite($this->sock,$IAC.$DONT.$opt);
   }
   else {
    // echo "where are we? c=".ord($c)."\n";
   }
  }
 }
}

/*
$telnet = new telnet("192.168.0.1",23);
echo $telnet->read_till("login: ");
$telnet->write("kongxx\r\n");
echo $telnet->read_till("password: ");
$telnet->write("KONGXX\r\n");
echo $telnet->read_till(":> ");
$telnet->write("ls\r\n");
echo $telnet->read_till(":> ");
echo $telnet->close();

*/
```

Comment: It can pass a command to an existing process? Can You write exapmle, please?

Comment: This game server have API or Interface(CLI/GUI)?

Comment: http://unturned-servers.net/help/api/

Comment: This API have not kick command. Where did you enter this command?

Comment: I have link on .exe file where I add params -nographics and -batchmode. After it server started in console mode. There I can type commands.

Comment: This is not a standard protocol.
I think you need to simulate the keyboard operation.
But PHP is not a good idea. I use Python do this.